Android: Very difficult to achieve the same layout proportions / aspect ratio between phones and tablets
When I say "the same layout proportions" I'm mainly referring to text sizes, but also to views in general.
I've always read that sp text size units are screen independent, but that's not completely true. I'll insert below two screenshots of my app welcome screen:
Welcome screen (PHONE):

Welcome screen (TABLET):

You can clearly see how texts does not retain proportion / aspect ratio.
I was doing deep research on the subject and found this next very interesting / cool library:
Intuit/ssp
This library does a fantastic job letting you get a real screen independent text size unit. You can see it in my next screenshot:
Welcome Screen with ssp (TABLET):

Now you can see how text sizes are much more coherent with the phone (if not exact).
All great until now, the library was a fantastic discovery, but now look my login screen:
Login (PHONE):

Login ssp in TextViews (TABLET):

Now in login screen in tablet you can see that if apply ssp to TextViews all texts look much better according to phone proportions, but the EditTexts look small.
Then I tried applying ssp to all TextViews and EditTexts:
Login ssp to all views (TABLET):

And you can see how, again, it looks much better.
What's the problem then?
I'm quite convinced with this last approach, applying ssp to all views text sizes, but two issues arise from this:

I will have to modify all views in my app (this is not a problem, but I have quite a lot).
The aspect ratio of some elements is still not retained, for example, look how the teal color background layout in a phone looks much more square than in a tablet (I'm also starting to doubt if dp, which I mostly use for padding / margin are screen independent units).

With all this, I'm a bit confused about how we, developers, should handle this in order to have a consistent layout between phones and tablets, and my main concern before going on with changing all views in my app to use ssp (a big task) is to be sure I'm going in the right direction.
In the GitHub page it clearly says:
"Use it carefully! for example, in most cases you still need to design a different layout for tablets."
So, this is also one of my concerns.
What do you have to say guys?
Is there any better approach to deal with this?
Edit: Having a different layout for tablets.
Forgot to mention that guys, but in the past I had a different layout for tablets, what in my opinion is a very bad idea / option, because you have two copies from every layout, and as any layout modification is needed you always have to remember to modify it twice, so no!
I've finally moved to only one layout trying to get the best match between both screens, and that's what leads to the origin of this post.
Edit 2:
After reading the valuable comments some of you, guys, have left, I still think that trying to achieve a consistent / good looking layout in both, phones and tablets, having only one layout file would be the best way to go, mainly in terms of maintainability, so, taking your comments definitely into account, I'll try to achieve that.
Now, after reading one comments saying the buttons in my welcome screen look huge in the tablet, a new concern arises to my mind.
Should having an exact (or quite similar) aspect ratio in a tablet compared to a phone screen, even having bigger buttons, be considered a better approach than a screen with smaller (maybe less rough) buttons but with a lot of blank (empty) space or viceversa? Which of the two is a more general approach?

Hi @Computable, and thanks for your input. I've already read that and agree with you, but in my case, this library helped me not only to have a consistent welcome screen, but also to have a consistent drawer navigation menu, which in a tablet was looking much smaller that in a phone. For the moment I applied ssp to all textviews in my app, but haven't started to migrate all views yet, this is a big task, and I definitely have to be very sure before going on. Let's see what other guys have to say.

I think you are misunderstanding what sp and dp are meant to do - they're meant to provide the same physical size. Of course they'll be a smaller proportion of a tablet screen - tablets are bigger devices. Your buttons also shouldn't be huge on a 10" tablet either though.

"Forgot to mention that guys, but in the past I had a different layout for tablets, what in my opinion is a very bad idea / option"....When using the view system this is actually the correct way to have layouts for different screen sizes. Most of your issues could be solved by using different dimens folder for specific screen sizes and then you reference the dimen values and sizing is handled by the OS automatically based on the values you have for each dimen folder. If you are trying to have 1 file for everything you are never going to have consistency.

Thanks for your input @ianhanniballake. Do you say that my buttons shouldn't be huge on a tablet because you have seen the screenshot I've attached? I mean, you say that in the welcome screen tablet screenshot my buttons look huge? Because in the screenshot they have the same exact proportion than in a phone, I not only used ssp for texts, but also weights for layout sizes, so to keep aspect ratio. Why shouldn't this be correct?

Hey @tyczj, thanks for your input, I was not considering the values-large folder with different dimens option, what indeed is an excellent approach, so I'll try to go this way and check how it looks (write it as an answer so I can close the question, please). Anyway, it would be good if you could answer to my dilemma on what is preferable, two screens that perfectly match in proportion / aspect ratio, but having huge buttons on a tablet, or a layout that in a tablet might look better, but without keeping the proportion and leaving a lot of blank (empty) screen space.

If there is something I don't like from SO is how so freely some people go and downvote without even leaving a reason. It took me a long while to prepare all the images in this question, which I consider a totally valid question, because I'm just asking for help about how to handle a specific programming issue related with layout. I'm not asking about how to prepare a Spanish Paella. It's a bit disgusting, I could go and downvote whoever I feel like, but I don't do it, in fact I've never done it, but if I do it, I would leave a reason, so the person understands what's supposedly wrong.

After reading the valuable comments of @tyczj and @ianhanniballake I started to have a look at different apps and noticed that the preferred way is to keep the same size of elements over keeping the same screen proportion, even when in the first case you will most likely end with a lot of blank / empty space, so this is the approach I decided to follow with my app.
As a tip to other developers facing the same concern, you definitely can have one same layout for both, phones and tablets, and it's the best approach in terms not only of clean code, but mainly maintainability.
There might be specific cases where you just need a separate layout for tablets, but in general (and it ended being my case) using different dimen for each you can accomplish almost everything with a single layout.
